# WinRT ArrangeOverride not called

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I`m creating a custom wrap panel which will contain a grid inside. The Custom panel will be an ItemsPanelTemplate for the groups of my gridview. What i`m a doing is that I store all my GridViewItems in the grid  and the only child will be the grid, or other grids if the items don`t fit in the current one(custom logic for placing items based on rowspan and colspan). I`m having problems with rising the ArrangeOvveride of the grid. Measureoverride is called for the grid when I call grid.Measure(availableSize) in the custom panel. What am I doing wrong ?